# Real tree and hyperbolicity

Tags: reference-request, trees, hyperbolic-geometry

I seek a proof of the following result due to Tits:

> **Theorem:** A path-connected $0$-hyperbolic metric space is a real tree.

Do you know any proof or reference?

Comment: What is the definition of "real tree" you are using? This is usually taken as the definition!

Comment: @SteveD: According to wikipedia, a real tree is a metric space $(M,d)$ such that for any $x, y$ in $M$ there is a unique arc from $x$ to $y$ and this arc is a geodesic segment. I use the same definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the result as Théorème 4.1 in Coornaert, Delzant and Papadopoulos' book *Géométrie et théorie des groupes, les groupes hyperboliques de Gromov*, where *path-connected* is replaced with *geodesic*; and in a document written by Steven N. Evans: [Probability and Real Trees](http://statistics.berkeley.edu/sites/default/files/tech-reports/721.pdf) (theorem 3.40), where *path-connected* is replaced with *connected*.

Answer (score 2):

Might this be what you are looking for?

J. Tits, A "theorem of Lie-Kolchin" for trees, Contributions to Algebra: A Collection of Papers Dedicated to Ellis Kolchin, Academic Press, New York, 1977, pp. 377–388.

Comment: Unfortunately, the article does not contain the above result.

Comment: @Seirios Please accept my apologies for having sent you in the wrong direction.

Comment: Even so, I found other interesting things!